# can I find the cosine inverse to find the angle of a triangle

Tags: php, math, php-5.6

I am trying to find the angle of a triangle I have complete most of the work using this formula

[image]
now Problem is that how to find cos inverse in PHP I have  the code below to find the cosine inverse

```
echo acos(42/90);
```

it returns a float value, not angle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Trigonometric functions work with radians, not degrees, so you have to calculate

```
$AngleInDegrees = rad2deg(acos(42/90))
or
$AngleInDegrees = acos(42/90) * 180 / Pi();
```